# I want to get e-mail authentication

Tags: django, ajax, email

An authentication number function that generates eight random characters was implemented.

i inputted username, and mail. because i want to write searching password html and request it at view with Ajax.

When I enter my username and email, I want the authentication number to be sent to the email. At the same time, the code created in ajax should show the authentication number window.
but, it happened nothing.

what should i do...?
help me!

error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` WHAT'S THAT..?

First of all, I corrected the white page. I missed it. '>'

```
#html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="KO">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="{% static 'users/css/recovery_pw.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'users/css/default.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96379a54a1.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'users/js/recovery_pw.js' %}" </script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="title">
                  <h1>비밀번호 찾기</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <div class="id">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="등록하신 메일로 인증번호가 발송됩니다." name="email" maxlenth="20" autocomplete="off" value="{{ form.email.value|default_if_none:'' }}" required />
                  </div>
                  <div class="password">
                    <input type="username" placeholder="아이디를 입력하세요" name="username" maxlength="20" value="{{ form.username.value|default_if_none:'' }}" required />
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="btn">
                  <div class="btn-white" id="btn_white"><button type="submit">임시 비밀번호 발송</button></div>
              </div>
    
              <div class="loading-box">
                  <div id="loading"></div>
              </div>
    
          </div>
    
    </form>

    
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
#users/js/recovery_pw.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#find_pw').click(function () {
        $('#loading').replaceWith('<div id="loading_end" class="loading"></div>')

        // 걍 임의로 만든것 같음
        var name = $("#pw_form_name").val();
        var email = $("#pw_form_email").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/users/recovery/pw/find/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // loading_end 이걸 지움
                $('#loading_end').remove()
                alert('회원님의 이메일로 인증코드를 발송하였습니다.');

                // 나는 이메일전송버튼이지
                $('#btn_white').remove()
                $('#result_pw').replaceWith(
                    '<hr><div class="row justify-content-md-center"><form class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom:-15px; margin-top:-10px;"><div class="md-form md-outline"><label for="input_auth_num">인증번호 입력 (<span id="timeset"></span>)</label><input type="text" id="input_auth_num" class="form-control mx-sm-2" autofocus/></div></form>' +
                    '<button type="submit" name="auth_confirm" id="id_auth_confirm" class="btn btn-red" style="opacity: 90%; height:30%; margin-top:10px; font-size: 12px;"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;인증확인</button></div><hr>'
                )
                function countdown(elementName, minutes, seconds) {
                    var elementName, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;
                    function twoDigits(n) {
                        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
                    }
                    function updateTimer() {
                        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
                        if (msLeft < 1000) {
                            alert("인증시간이 초과되었습니다.");
                            $("" + elementName).remove();
                            cert_ok = false;
                            certificationNum = false;
                            location.href = "{% url 'recovery_pw' %}"
                        } else {
                            time = new Date(msLeft);
                            hours = time.getUTCHours();
                            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
                            $("" + elementName).html((hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits(mins) : twoDigits(mins))
                                + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds()));
                            setTimeout(updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500);
                        }
                    }
                    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
                    updateTimer();
                }
                countdown("#timeset", 5, 0);

                var user = response.result

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#id_auth_confirm').click(function () {
                        var input_auth_num = $("#input_auth_num").val();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/users/recovery/pw/auth/",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                'input_auth_num': input_auth_num,
                                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                location.href = "{% url 'recovery_pw_reset' %}";
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                if ($('#input_auth_num').val() == "") {
                                    alert('회원님의 이메일로 전송된 인증번호를 입력해주세요.');
                                } else {
                                    alert('인증번호가 일치하지 않습니다.');
                                }
                            },
                        });
                    })
                })
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#loading_end').remove()
                if (username == "" || email == "") {
                    alert('이름, 이메일을 모두 입력해주세요.');
                } else {
                    alert('입력하신 정보가 일치하지 않거나 존재하지 않습니다.');
                }
            },
        });
    })
});
```

```
#views.py
class RecoveryPwView(View):
    template_name = 'users/recovery_pw.html'
    recovery_pw = RecoveryPwForm

    def get(self, request):
        if request.method=='GET':
            form = self.recovery_pw(None)
            return render(request, self.template_name, { 'form':form, })


def ajax_find_pw_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    target_user = User.objects.get(username=username, email=email)

    if target_user:
        auth_num = email_auth_num()
        target_user.auth = auth_num 
        target_user.save()

        send_mail(
            'this is email verify',
            ['email'],
            html=render_to_string('users/recovery_email.html', {
                'auth_num': auth_num,
            }),
        )
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"result": target_user.username}, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type = "application/json")
```

```
#urls.py
path('recovery/pw/', RecoveryPwView.as_view(), name='recovery_pw'),
    path('recovery/pw/find/', views.ajax_find_pw_view, name='ajax_pw'),
    path('recovery/pw/auth/', views.auth_confirm_view, name='recovery_auth'),
    path('recovery/pw/reset/', views.auth_pw_reset_view, name='recovery_pw_reset'),
```

```
form

class RecoveryPwForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='id')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='email')

    class Meta:
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class CustomSetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    new_password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=16, 
        min_length=6, 
        label=_('새 비밀번호')
    )
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=16, 
        min_length=6, 
        label=_('새 비밀번호 확인')
    )
```

Comment: I think that the problem occurs because of url, so, try to leave a url blank in ajax because you are already using ajax in the same page of html, not in the separated javascript file

Comment: I created a new 'recovery_pw.js' file and put the Jquery code in it. And when I entered my email and name, an empty page was rendered.... what's that..?

Comment: If the input is correct, there should be a form to enter the authentication number sent by e-mail, but only empty page displayed.

Comment: there's a mistake I see over there, you are trying to use csrf_toke with get method, the csrf_token is used when you are using sensitive request such as: create, delete, and so on but since you try to use get method the data will not become hidden so, you shouldn't use csrf_token in that case

Comment: please include the form you are trying to use here too, which makes me able to see what you want to do exactly and what is the main problem

Comment: I didn't use the include form.

Comment: sorry, I mean RecoveryPwForm form, I need to see what is that form refers to? what are the fields that are handled by?

Comment: i added form and fixed html file!

Comment: RecoveryPwForm handles names and emails.

Comment: What are you referring to by 'it happened nothing` the popup or the entire thing?

Comment: I didn't get the authentication number in the email. In addition, when requesting an authentication number, the authentication number input form must be created in recovry_pw.html as the jquery code in 'recovery_pw.js'. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try printing out the data that is being sent using Ajax. If the data isn't printing there's a problem with your js.

Comment: Where're the elements that you're referring in your js

Comment: you mean <script src="{% static 'users/js/recovery_pw.js' %}" </script>?? it's users/js/recovery_pw.js...

Comment: I'm sorry. I really don't know what you're asking.....

Answer (score 1):

since you are using the get method into the View model, you can use it directly without checking by method and that is what that function does for ease

**Note:-**
now you handle the request method by get method which you can't use csrf_token into your form

now the problem is that, you are trying to use get method to send data then, you want to get this data in ajax by Post method which you won't receive any data of course in addition to, that you are trying to execute the separate function in the view which cause a problem where the function will never execute because the form doesn't know where should it send the data in after the request is created.

so, now you can remove the additional function you use and try to use and include what you want in the one view to prevent the confusion so, follow the solution like so:

```
class RecoveryPwView(View):
    template_name = 'users/recovery_pw.html'
    recovery_pw = RecoveryPwForm

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.recovery_pw(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, { 'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.recovery_pw(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            target_user = User.objects.get(username=username, email=email)
        
        # do send email here

        # return the render that you want to finish by post method here
```

## html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner-box">
          <div class="title">
              <h1>비밀번호 찾기</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
              {% comment %} <div class="id">
                <input type="email" placeholder="등록하신 메일로 인증번호가 발송됩니다." name="email" maxlenth="20" autocomplete="off" value="{{ form.email.value|default_if_none:'' }}" required />
              </div>
              <div class="username">
                <input type="username" placeholder="아이디를 입력하세요" name="username" maxlength="20" value="{{ form.username.value|default_if_none:'' }}" required />
              </div> {% endcomment %}
              {% for field in form %}
                <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div>{{ field }}</div>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <div class="btn">
              <div class="btn-white" id="btn_white"><button type="submit">임시 비밀번호 발송</button></div>
          </div>

          <div class="loading-box">
              <div id="loading"></div>
          </div>

      </div>

</form>
```

Now this solution is not completed, because I'm not sure from understanding exactly what you want to do but at least you can see that there's something new happen for your problem to find the min problem, the issue now will come from Ajax just let me know what you are facing after that

Comment: what...? ummmm why did you remove<div class='id">??

Comment: if you want to leave it you can, but because you are using the form from Django so, it will be better to use it or you can remove the Django form and leave that eventually, it's up to you but I did that for clear as long you will not use the Django form

Comment: you mean, {{form.email.value|default_if_none:'}}} it's not need it?

Comment: I changed the code as you told me. then, now i faced new error.
ValueError: The view users.views.RecoveryPwView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[29/Mar/2022 10:22:03] "POST /recovery/pw/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65243

Comment: did you focus on the comments I provided in my answer? you will see that I typed: # return the render that you want to finish by post method here, which means that you should return your own response, or maybe you can do some tricks such as redirect()